# How to build a cross compiler of GHC in Alpinelinux?

Tags: ghc, alpine-linux

I have done following steps in Alpinelinux v3.9 x86_64 and got error.

1. Run bootstrap.sh in aport to get aarch64-alpine-linux-musl-* tools.
2. Build and install llvm6 in x86_64.
3. Link all aarch64-alpine-linux-musl-* to aarch64-unknown-linux-*.
4. Configure ghc 8.6.3 only with "--target=aarch64-unknown-linux".

   ```
   Configure completed successfully.

      Building GHC version  : 8.6.3
             Git commit id  : 31cd867e4d37072c3ce1d51efadc94e66ddc1c28

      Build platform        : x86_64-alpine-linux
      Host platform         : x86_64-alpine-linux
      Target platform       : aarch64-unknown-linux

      Bootstrapping using   : /usr/bin/ghc
         which is version   : 8.4.3

      Using (for bootstrapping) : gcc
      Using gcc                 : aarch64-unknown-linux-gcc
         which is version       : 8.2.0
      Building a cross compiler : YES
      Unregisterised            : NO
      hs-cpp       : aarch64-unknown-linux-gcc
      hs-cpp-flags : -E -undef -traditional
      ar           : aarch64-unknown-linux-ar
      ld           : aarch64-unknown-linux-ld.gold
      nm           : aarch64-unknown-linux-nm
      libtool      : 
      objdump      : aarch64-unknown-linux-objdump
      ranlib       : aarch64-unknown-linux-ranlib
      windres      : 
      dllwrap      : 
      genlib       : 
      Happy        :  ()
      Alex         :  ()
      Perl         : /usr/bin/perl
      sphinx-build : 
      xelatex      : 

      Using LLVM tools
         clang : 
         llc   : llc
         opt   : opt

      HsColour was not found; documentation will not contain source links

      Tools to build Sphinx HTML documentation available: NO
      Tools to build Sphinx PDF documentation available: NO
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------

   For a standard build of GHC (fully optimised with profiling), type (g)make.

   To make changes to the default build configuration, copy the file
   mk/build.mk.sample to mk/build.mk, and edit the settings in there.

   For more information on how to configure your GHC build, see
      http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building
   ```
5. Make.

   ```
   ===--- building final phase
   make --no-print-directory -f ghc.mk phase=final all
   "ld" -z noexecstack -r  -o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/HSghc-prim-0.5.3.o  libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Classes.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Debug.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/IntWord64.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Magic.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/PrimopWrappers.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Tuple.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/Types.o   libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/atomic.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/bswap.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/clz.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/ctz.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/debug.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/longlong.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/pdep.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/pext.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/popcnt.o libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/cbits/word2float.o   
   ld: libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
   ld: libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
   ld: libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
   make[1]: *** [libraries/ghc-prim/ghc.mk:4: libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/HSghc-prim-0.5.3.o] Error 1
   make: *** [Makefile:127: all] Error 2

   $ file ./libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o
   ./libraries/ghc-prim/dist-install/build/GHC/CString.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. After remove ld.gold and copy ld as ld.gold, building process passed. Simple test passed.